# Ubuntu Touch -Text message Unity icon not showing notifications

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, icons, notification, sms

I have noticed that when I receive a text message (SMS) on my Ubuntu phone, i do not receive plus 1 notification in the text message icon on the unity bar. Without this notification, I am finding that I am missing or forgetting about received messages.

When I receive a new Telegram message, the Telegram Unity icon shows a plus 1, so my thought is that the text message icon should too.

I don't believe that I an the only person experiencing this issue, but I have looked for this on Google and this site and cannot find anything that directly relates to it. The closest bug I could see is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/media-hub/+bug/1544477 but that is related to no sound for SMS notifications.

Comment: I am sure that I remember this working before, but not sure as I mainly use.telegram these days.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/messaging-app/+bug/1530371

Comment: @ponsky, as always you are a great help. Thank you for providing the Launchpad number.

Comment: It looks like the status has now moved to Incomplete → Confirmed. So hopefully, we should see this resolved soon.